# No DesignTimeAgent found error in dialogflow prebuilt agent

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I was trying to import some prebuilt dialogflow agent, and I am always getting the following error:

```
com.google.apps.framework.request.NotFoundException: No DesignTimeAgent found for project 'alarm-vdhp'.

com.google.apps.framework.request.BadRequestException: Validate AgentModel failed of the following reason: AgentModel.defaultTimezone is required but was not provided AgentModel.defaultTimezone is not a supported timezone.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In "agent.json", provide a default timezone, for example:

```
{
  "description": "",
  "language": "en",
  "enabledDomainFeatures": [],
  "googleAssistant": {
    "googleAssistantCompatible": false,
    "welcomeIntentSignInRequired": false,
    "startIntents": [],
    "endIntentIds": [],
    "oAuthLinking": {
      "required": false,
      "grantType": "AUTH_CODE_GRANT"
    },
    "voiceType": "MALE_1"
  },
  **"defaultTimezone": "America/New_York",**
  "webhook": {
    "url": "",
    "headers": {
      "": ""
    },
    "available": true,
    "useForDomains": false
  },
  "isPrivate": true,
  "customClassifierMode": "use.instead",
  "mlMinConfidence": 0.2,
  "onePlatformApiVersion": "v2"
}
```